# Including a XML file crashes my application

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I try to unify my layouts and so i want to reuse some UI elements. If i try to include those elements in my *main.xml* the app crashes with

> 02-15 13:07:02.470: E/AndroidRuntime(16588): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

My XML looks like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <include layout="@layout/include_topbar"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- include_topbar -->
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/topbar_linearlayout">
        <include layout="@layout/include_icon"/>
        <include layout="@layout/include_topbar_title"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>

<!-- include_icon -->
<merge xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<View
    android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
/></merge>

<!-- include_topbar_title -->
<merge xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/bla"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/></merge>

<!-- topbar_linearlayout -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="topbar_linearlayout">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">58dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Edit: Don't use `<merge>`, then it will work...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/topbar_linearlayout">
    <include layout="@layout/include_icon"/>
    <include layout="@layout/include_topbar_title"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- include_icon -->
<View xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer in Exception provided...  "You must supply a layout_width attribute."

So, set the layout_width and layout_height for both the include statements.

Comment: shouldn't they be included from e.g. include_icon.xml. also, the app crashes with the same error even if i provide them.

Comment: This width and height is for this layout to allocate the space. Mainly if you want to use the same layout with different sizes in different UI's... So, just set it as wrap_content for both height and width

Comment: the [doc](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) doesn't use layout_xxx. and as said, even if i specify it, my app crashes.

Comment: Try removing the merge in all the files.. (include files)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/topbar_linearlayout">
```

does not have width and height attribute which need to be specified.

Comment: even if i do it crashes. also i thought it takes the width/height from topbar_linearlayout?